# Check for hard disk errors / signs of failure on CentOS Server

Tags: centos, hard-drive, corruption

What's the best way to check for HDD errors and early signs of failure on CentOS?

Comment: how frequent should the checks be? daily - weekly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend installing smartmon (http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/smartmontools/wiki) to your machine this is some software which can check the health of your disks otherwise its going to be checking /var/log/messages or /var/log/syslog for any mentions of scsi errors

Comment: smartmon seems it, although its stats mention it'd catch only 60% of failing drives.. if i set smartmon to scan daily, would this actually help the hdd die faster -- it's a seagate 7200.10?

Comment: @inac smartmon will help hdds to die faster? Where did you read this? Please add an URL.

Answer (score 3):

```
dmesg
```

The kernel will log any diagnostic messages about I/O devices, so you can check those messages out with the dmesg command.

Comment: but you'd have to run this manually or cronjob dmesg dump to vi?

Comment: either.  you could create a script to dump it with "dmesg > dmesg.dump.txt" and run that daily with cron.

Answer (score 2):

SMART monitoring is a good way.  As root, `smartctl -a /dev/hda`, where hda is the drive you want... could be hdb, sda, etc.  Also recommend setting your email address in /etc/aliases as the person who should get root's mail.

That's a very vague answer though.  If you have a server made by any of the big manufacturers (Dell, HP, etc), chances are there are better monitoring capabilities available.

Answer (score 1):

You can run fsck on the device to check for errors.

Answer (score 0):

As Paul says, the SMART logs are a good place to check.

I'd also recommend running [BadBlocks](http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net/badblockhowto.html). If you've got a RAID card, you might have to use the monitoring on that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try full check of partition /dev/sda1 (for example) as

```
fsck -f /dev/sda1
```

or, try full write-read non-descructive test of given partition

```
badblocks -vn /dev/sda1
```

Comment: `/dev/sda1 is mounted; it's not safe to run badblocks!`

Comment: `e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.`

Comment: @030 Drop to a runlevel where the main disk is not mounted.