# SLES9 iostat -En

Tags: linux, sles

With Solaris if I do iostat -En I can check if my disk has any stats soft error or hard error.

```
$iostat -En
c1t0d0          Soft Errors: 0 Hard Errors: 0 Transport Errors: 0
Vendor: SEAGATE  Product: ST373207LSUN72G  Revision: 045A Serial No: 3532D7ZL    
Size: 73.40GB <73400057856 bytes>
Media Error: 0 Device Not Ready: 0 No Device: 0 Recoverable: 0
Illegal Request: 0 Predictive Failure Analysis: 0
```

But the same command doesn't work with SUSE Linux.Is there an alternative command use in SLES9?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `dmesg` command to look for any device errors logged by the kernel.

Here is a similar question for a different Linux distro, but should be applicable to you:

[Check for hard disk errors / signs of failure on CentOS Server](https://serverfault.com/questions/150471/check-for-hard-disk-errors-signs-of-failure-on-centos-server)

Answer (score 0):

I believe solaris iostat reads this data from drive's SMART, so you might try to use smartctl/smartd (and it shows a lot of additional information): `smartctl --all /dev/sda`